# Auth server for validate IdentityServer4 access tokens

Tags: identityserver4

We are using IdentityServer4("http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html") to protect our APIs, actually we have multiple APIs and we want to protect these APIs with IdentityServer4(i.e via generating access tokens) but we have questions regarding validating the access tokens,Do we need to create separate auth server for validate IdentityServer4's access tokens?

Actually our APIs are already build and deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Once you specify to your api, that it should use IdentityServer for authentication, and of course you specify the authority, you don't need to do anything, except registering this API in Identity Server, and put the `AuthorizeAttribute` where you need it in the API.